# Java Statement.executeQuery SQL error with ORDER BY and/or LIMIT- not sure what the correct format

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to get a result set out of a JDBC database using Statement.executeQuery. It needs to be ordered by the first column, and limited to 1000 rows. Right now, the sql statement I'm using is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME ORDER BY COLUMN1NAME LIMIT 1000;
```

This is just giving me SQL errors. There's clearly something wrong, but I don't really know sql well enough to figure it out.

The database is Postgres.

Comment: What do the errors say?

Comment: What database is this for? not all of them use `limit` for this sort of thing.

Comment: You have to create a try/catch block around Statement.executeQuery, so all I get from the errors are what I put in the catch block (which, at this point, is just a println and a printStackTrace). It's for a postgres database.

Comment: Okay. What is being outputted? And put a breakpoint inside your `catch` so you can inspect the exception thrown.

Comment: THat syntax looks valid for Postgres, you'll need to pull out the errors.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you use [`Statement#getMaxRows`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setMaxRows-int-) instead and let your JDBC driver manages this (if supported):

```
final int MAX_ROWS = 1000;
//...
String sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLENAME ORDER BY COLUMN1NAME";
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
stmt.setMaxRows(MAX_ROWS);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

Otherwise, provide the specific database engine you're working with and use the proper statements.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it's not the syntax. The column name was being retrieved from the wrong resultset. Sorry.